# Casting and Convert.ToInt32() behave different in C#?

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion, numeric-conversion

Here a simple C# piece of code:

```
Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds);
//which brings me 300000

(int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).Milliseconds;
//which brings me 0
```

Why would casting `(int)` result is different when compared to `Convert.ToInt32()`?

Shouldn't both bring the same result?

Comment: I think they have different overflow and rounding behavior. But that's not responsible for your issue here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first version you're using the [`TotalMilliseconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx) property - in the second you're using [`Milliseconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.milliseconds.aspx).

To give a simpler example, with no casting or calling to `Convert.ToInt32`:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(49);
Console.WriteLine(ts.Hours); // 1 (it's two days and one hour) 
Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalHours); // 49 (it's 49 hours in total)
```

Comment: hey Jon. Indeed I was about to delete this question. Lol. That Milliseconds is the problem!

Answer (score 3):

The milliseconds is just the milliseconds PORTION of the 5 seconds.  Use TotalMilliseconds on the second one as well.

Answer (score 2):

In you first example you use TotalMilliseconds and then just Milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that in the second example you are calling the `.Milliseconds` property, not the `.TotalMilliseconds` property.

The former returns 5 minutes in milliseconds. The latter returns the millisecond portion of 5 minutes, which is zero.

The cast vs. convert is a red herring!

Answer (score 1):

You left out "Total" from the second line.  So, this works.

```
(int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 1):

They're the same... you've used TotalMilliseconds vs Milliseconds. The first is the total number of milliseconds in  5 minutes, whereas the second is the remainder, or the value which would be displayed if you wanted to display the time IE the '000' in  '00:05:00.000'

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not the conversion but that you are comparing TotalMilliseconds and Milliseconds!